# How to check if an algebraic variety is disconnected, using analytic tools?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{R}$.

I wonder if it is possible to check if $V$ is disconnected using analytic tools?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean separated or disconnected? The title and body of the question don't agree.

Comment: I mean disconnected .

Comment: disconnected in which topology?

Comment: In Hausdorff topology.

Comment: This sounds almost like Hilbert's 16th problem. But if I give you the real elliptic curve $y^2=x(x^2-1)$, can you show me how, without knowing the graph, you would show *analytically* that it has two components? We know to look for separating lines, but this obviously won't work in general.

Comment: Dear @Ted Shifrin  may thanks for your answer. I realize that I asked a very difficult question.